# Datatable evitar que la pagina borre columnas jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo creada un `datatable`, todo funciona perfecto, el problema esque inserto datos por `input:text` mi problema empieza al moverme entre paginación ya que borra las filas con datos que lleva el textbox, es decir al momento de moverme a la pagina 2, se borran los `td`para crear los nuevos. Debido a que estoy usando campos `input:hidden` me los borra también evitando enviar el array de `inputs` para guardar, es decir solo me guarda los datos de la pagina en la que me encuentro. ***Hay alguna forma de paginar los registros sin tener que borrar la información cada que pagine?***

Comment: Estas agregando los nuevos renglones por medio de js, jquery o por la función de datatable?

Comment: Cargo todos los datos directamente en una tabla y median datatable, simplemente pagina eso. Inserto la información en c/u de las filas en los inputs, formando un array `name="precios[]"` pero al moverme de pagina, solo envia los datos de la pagina actual, y no todos.

Comment: ¿Te refieres al momento de recorrer la tabla para tomar los datos?

Comment: así es, solo toma lo de la paginación actual

Answer (score 0):

Para recorrer toda la tabla y no solo la pagina actual utiliza la función de [iterator()](https://datatables.net/blog/2017-05-31)

```
dtTabla.rows().iterator('row', function (context, index) {
    var node = $(this.row(index).node());
    lstid.push({
       id: node.find("div").data().id,
       numero: node.find(":eq(0)").text(),
       fecha: node.find(":eq(4)").text()
    });
});
```

Comment: hago el envió de la información mediante formulario, el cual recibe un array de la información capturada